# Basic plugin analysis failed

Tags: shopware6

I have created a theme (for Shopware 6.4). But, when I upload the zip to my merchant area I get this error:

```
Basic plugin analysis failed.

The information provided in the composer.json file is invalid
Context: [
 • required.shopware/core#mismatch: The compatibility in your composer.json "required"."shopware/core" was set to Version 6.4.* These versions are missing in your account to fulfill this requirement: 6.4.20.2
]
```

I have set the compatibility of the theme to the 6.4 branch (6.4.0.0 - 6.20.1).

In composer.json I have:

```
"require": {
  "shopware/core": "6.4.*"
}
```

So why this error and how to fix it?

UPDATE: To solve the issue I needed to have two wildcards in the version. Like this:

```
6.4.*.*
```

/Magnus

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you wouldn't want to support the upcoming minor release `6.4.20.2`? There shouldn't be breaking changes between minor versions. I would select it ahead of time. If you feel uncomfortable about checking that version in advance, you'll have to exclude upcoming versions in your requirements as well.

```json
{
    "require": {
        "shopware/core": ">=6.4.0, <6.4.20.2"
    }
}
```

Come `6.4.20.2` you'd obviously then have to upload another version without the exclusion if you want to support the minor release.

Comment: I forgot about the latest 6.4 version.
Updated the composer to:
"shopware/core": ">=6.4.0, <=6.4.20.2"
But still the same error. I'm confused what "These versions are missing in your account to fulfill this requirement: 6.4.20.2" actually mean.